# ListView Item Selected Show Details on Detail Page in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I Do have a List of Data in listvew and also i add one Detail Button in each row of list.
my Command is by clicking on the button Bind the empId with button and Load a new list  that contain all that user Data

```
<Button Name="detailshow" Click="Detailshow_Click"  CommandParameter="{Binding Path=empID}">
```

and also the Query is :

```
Button _button = (Button)sender;
            string empID = _button.CommandParameter.ToString();

            SqlCeConnection //stuffff
            objCon.Open();

            String str = "SELECT e.empID, e.empname FROM employee e WHERE empID= " + empID;

            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(str, objCon);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            ListViewEmployeeDetails.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Well Simply its not work... its doesn't show any data

Answer (score -1):

Did you use the debugger and inspect the value for empID?

empID will very likely contain the string "{Binding Path=empID}" and not an ID value as you probably expect.

CommandParameter is not a dependency property/object and so is not bindable.

[MSDN ButtonBase.CommandParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.commandparameter.aspx)

Comment: CommandParameter is a DependencyProperty (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.commandparameterproperty.aspx). I can't see what would it be good for if it wasn't...

Comment: You are right, my mistake. There are a lot of places in wpf where parameters are just plain clr props. F.i. converterparameter. Anyway did you check if the commandparameter has the expected value?